# Stripe PaymentElement component: Only allow USA credit card

Tags: stripe-payments

I've successfully implemented stripe payment into my website using Payment Intents and am accepting payments using the `<PaymentElement>` component from the [react-stripe-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stripe/react-stripe-js) library. However, it's giving the user the option to enter a card from any country:

[image: stripe payment]

I don't see an option in the [PaymentElement](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element) docs describing an option to limit which countries I want to accept payments from. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: There's no automatic setting to disable specific card types or cards issued in certain countries. This is something you'd need to manage yourself using the [Payment Methods API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods). Alternatively you could configure [Radar](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules) rules to block cards from certain countries.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thanks for the answer. Do you think injecting javascript into the `PaymentIntent` element which hides the Country select field makes sense in this case?

Comment: You can't interfere with the iframe of the Payment Element, no. Those are hosted by Stripe for the purposes of PCI compliance.

Comment: Gotcha. So if I update my Payment Method API then I can make the dropdown only have the allowed countries?

Comment: You won't be able to remove options from the Country dropdown, no. Instead you could [disable](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-options-fields-billingDetails-address) the address collection from the Payment Element entirely.

Comment: Ok, so addresses are not needed for Credit card payment?

Comment: Generally not, no.

Comment: @JonathanSteele the API you linked says you can disable the address if you use `createElement()`, is there no way to do this when using `<PaymentElement />`?

Comment: Yep, you can pass the [`options` hash](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#element-components) to the `<PaymentElement />` component.